# Java Compile Error, cannot find symbol

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Getting the error "Cannot Fin Symbol", but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise6_1{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
        int numberStudents = input.nextInt();
        int[] studentScores = new int[numberStudents];
        System.out.print("Enter " + numberStudents + " Scores: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++);{
            studentScores[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have semicolon after the "for" cycle.

Should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++) {
    studentScores[i] = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an ; after the for loop.

Correct impl :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of students: ");
        int numberStudents = input.nextInt();
        int[] studentScores = new int[numberStudents];
        System.out.print("Enter " + numberStudents + " Scores: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++)
        {
            studentScores[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last semicolon in the line

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++);{
```

should be removed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++);{
        studentScores[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Here You have ended the for loop with a semi-colon , which results in the termination of the loop at that point . That's why it shows it can't find symbol  *i*  , As it is out of the scope of the for loop.